# Node: 12 procesos abiertos a la vez

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, pm2

Acabo de terminar de configurar en local en Windows 10 -tras dar muchas vueltas- una aplicación web (Tabulae) que corre sobre Node.js (y MongoDB) y creo que he hecho algo mal al instalar PM2, porque al arrancarla funciona pero se despliegan doce ventanitas tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que no hay manera de cerrar, por otro lado, salvo que reinicies el ordenador.

Es difícil detallar lo que he hecho porque fue bastante tortuoso, así que supongo que alguna de mis múltiples pruebas es la que está provocando este imprevisto, pero he anotado los pasos que creo que deberían ser los apropiados de cara a replicar el proceso:

Tras instalar Mongo, Node, restaurar las bases de datos con un mongorestore y configurar los archivos que requiere la aplicación para que apunten en la dirección apropiada, desde el CMD en modo administrador se haría:

1. Instalar las dependencias de Node (desde el directorio en el que se encuentra `package.json`): `npm install`
2. Instalar PM2: `npm install pm2 -g`
3. Instalar PM2 como servicio de Windows: `npm install pm2-windows-startup -g`

**Edición del punto 3**: Parece que faltan comandos adicionales:

```
npm i pm2-windows-service -g

pm2-service-install
```

Y tras este último te hace una serie de preguntas, empezando por:

```
? Perform environment setup (recommended)?
```

Le diga `Yes` o `No` le da igual, se queda ahí pillado, pero diciéndole que no al menos parece instalar el servicio.

4. Configurar PM2 para que inicie Tabulae después de arrancar/reiniciar la máquina: `pm2 startup install`
5. Arrancar Tabulae con PM2 (desde el directorio en el que se encuentra `pm2-start.json`): `pm2 start pm2-start.json`

Y tras este paso aparecen las doce -molestas- ventanitas.

6. Salvar el estado de los procesos de PM2: `pm2 save`

Si reinicias y accedes a la app a través de localhost como es menester, inicialmente rechaza la conexión hasta que aparecen las doce ventanitas, momento en que ya se puede empezar a trabajar con ella.

¿Se os ocurre a qué puede deberse?

Un saludo y gracias por adelantado.

**Solución parcial**: Bien, tras desinstalar y reinstalar siguiendo los pasos de arriba, ahora mismo he solventado el problema de las ventanitas pero cada vez que se reinicia el servicio PM2, sea manualmente o porque se reinicia Windows, la aplicación deja de funcionar y requiere ejecutar de nuevo el punto 5 o hacer un `pm2 resurrect` para que arranque de nuevo.

Comment: Hola Javier. PM2 es un administrador de procesos. El comportamiento inicial que tiene es porque crea una aplicación por cada núcleo que se le asigne. En un entorno en producción nos permite mejorar el tiempo de respuesta de nuestra aplicación evitando cuellos de botellas. Una de las características es el hot reload. Esto es, cuando el equipo o una aplicación falla el gestor reinicia las aplicaciones y/o servicios hasta que esta en linea de nuevo. Esto incluye reinicios inesperados, esperados, apagones, fallos en el sistema, etc. En pocas palabras esta echo para lo que quieres evitar.